# Что значит "Connect to MySQL from the MySQL command line client"?

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Объясните пожалуйста попроще (только начинаю изучать Docker), что значит "Connect to MySQL from the MySQL command line client" (Подключитесь к MySQL из клиента командной строки MySQL)? Описание данного способа подключения прочитал здесь https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql, но не понял сути.
Непонятны оказались также значения some-network, -uexample-user, -hsome.mysql.host и -usome-mysql-user - как они задаются и откуда их нужно брать?
Вот полный текст этого раздела:

> Connect to MySQL from the MySQL command line client The following
> command starts another mysql container instance and runs the mysql
> command line client against your original mysql container, allowing
> you to execute SQL statements against your database instance:

```
$ docker run -it --network some-network --rm mysql mysql -hsome-mysql -uexample-user -p ...
```

> where some-mysql is the name of your original mysql container
> (connected to the some-network Docker network).
>
> This image can also be used as a client for non-Docker or remote
> instances:

$ docker run -it --rm mysql mysql -hsome.mysql.host -usome-mysql-user -p

Comment: Есть предположение, что за докер вы взялись рановато. Сначала нужно освоить работу с командной строкой unix, а так же базовые понятия из сетей: хост, домен, порт и так далее

Comment: Что такое хост, домен и порт знаю, с командной строкой unix знаком - подымал сервер Debian для java web сервиса на виртуальном хостенге (java+tomcat+mysql+nginx), правда с проксированием между nginx и tomcat не получилось, но в целом знаком

Answer (score 1):

Постараюсь тогда чутка изменить эту строку, что бы навести на мысль:

```
$ docker run -it --network some-nerwork --rm mysql mysql -hlocalhost -udbuser -p ...
```

или же так:

```
$ docker run -it --network some-network --rm mysql mysql -h 192.168.15.15 -u dbuser -p ...
```

С some-network -разбираться по ситуации, этот параметр докера, а все остальное это части командной строки подключения к mysqld при помощи консольного клиента myslq

Comment: Т.е. мы создаем какую то сеть `--network some-network`, вызываем в этой сети `mysql-server`? А вот это что такое `-h 192.168.15.15 -u dbuser?`

Comment: Владимир, у меня такой же вопрос :)
Вы в итоге разобрались ?
Если да - можете ответ написать ?

Comment: Ребята, "-h 192.168.15.15 -u dbuser" это параметры самого mysql-клиента. И их все если надо можно почитать набрав man mysql. Когда вы работаете с приложением внутри контейнера, то вы параметры передаете и системе управления контейнерами, и своему приложению внутри